# Populating a list of collapsible DIV dynamically from a loop

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, dom

I am trying to add a collapsible DIV with the JQuery mobile CSS dynamically to a page.The list of DIVs and the associated content is populated in a for loop.

```
items.forEach(function (entity) {
  document.getElementById("auditListHolder").innerHTML = document.getElementById("auditListHolder").innerHTML +
    "<div data-role='collapsible' data-collapsed='false'>" +
    "<h3>" + entity.AuditName + "</h3>" +
    "<p>" + entity.Content + "</p>" +
    "</div>";
});
```

I tried using this code to add a DIV to existing set of DIVs on each iteration of the loop, but the DIV does not render as a collapsible DIV. The list appears as normal DIV with content as shown below:

[image]

Is there a problem with the code or can there be problem with CSS.

Comment: After the loop add `$('[data-role=collapsible').collapsible();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call widget enhancement `.collapsible();` after appending elements dynamically.

```
$('selector').collapsible();
```

> selector = `[data-role=collapsible]`, `#id`, `.class` etc...

Answer (score 1):

Try calling .trigger("create") on the element auditListHolder after the loop!

Comment: adding '$('[data-role=collapsible').collapsible();' solved the issue @Ricky